# Passing array of object to controller in asp.net 6 (core)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

I'm trying to pass an array of objects into an asp .net core controller method using jQuery's ajax() function. When I enter the exporttocsv() C# controller method, the argument "data" is null. I've tried this using a type of List for the argument, but that doesn't work either. What am I doing wrong?

//model=[{
"grantNumber": "1R01MD018293-01",
"award": 731899,
"awardCode": "R01",
"awardDate": "2023-03-18T12:03:00",
"startDate": "2023-03-18T00:00:00",
"endDate": "2027-11-30T12:11:00",
"fiscalYear": 2023,
"projectTitle": "Epigenetic aging,",
"abstract": "PROJECT ABSTRACT",
"thesaurus": "37 weeks gestation;Acceleration;Address;",
"organization": "UNIVERSITY OF CENTRAL FLORIDA",
"department": "NONE",
"address": "ORLANDO,FL,UNITED STATES-328263231",
"city": "ORLANDO",
"state": "FL",
"zip": "328263231",
"country": "UNITED STATES",
"contactFirstName": "CARMEN",
"contactLastName": "GIURGESCU",
"contactTitle": "PROFESSOR, ASSOCIATE DEAN FOR RESEARCH",
"contactEmail": "",
"phone": "",
"fax": "",
"awardType": "1",
"kw": "",
"hits": 0,
"labUrl": ""
},

{
"grantNumber": "1R01AI168182-01A1",
"award": 759454,
"awardCode": "R01",
"awardDate": "2023-03-17T12:03:00",
"startDate": "2023-03-17T00:00:00",
"endDate": "2028-02-29T12:02:00",
"fiscalYear": 2023,
"projectTitle": "Influence of the nasal microbiome on host susceptibility and response to respiratory viruses",
"abstract": "PROJECT SUMMARY",
"thesaurus": "2019-nCoV;",
"organization": "GEORGE WASHINGTON UNIVERSITY",
"department": "PUBLIC HEALTH & PREV MEDICINE",
"address": "WASHINGTON,DC,UNITED STATES-200520042",
"city": "WASHINGTON",
"state": "DC",
"zip": "200520042",
"country": "UNITED STATES",
"contactFirstName": "CINDY",
"contactLastName": "LIU",
"contactTitle": "ASSISTANT RESEARCH PROFESSOR",
"contactEmail": "",
"phone": "",
"fax": "",
"awardType": "1",
"kw": "",
"hits": 0,
"labUrl": ""
}
]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function check() {
        debugger
        var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(@ViewBag.alldata));
        $.ajax({
              contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: "/Home/exporttocsv",
            data: { "data": JSON.stringify(model) },
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {

                location.href = '@Url.Action("DownloadCSV", "Home")?success=' + data;

            }
        });
    };

</script>



public class HomeController: Controller
    {
    [HttpPost]
            public string exporttocsv(List<ShowNihSearchData> data)
            {  
             // do stuff with data here...
            }
}
```

Comment: what is the message in browser f12 developer tools->console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function check() {
        debugger
        var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(@ViewBag.alldata));
        var modeldata= JSON.stringify(model);
        $.ajax({
            ContentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: "/Home/exporttocsv",
            data: { "data": modeldata },
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                debugger;
                console.log(data);
                    location.href = '@Url.Action("DownloadCSV", "Home")?success=' + data;

            }
        });
</script>

public class HomeController: Controller
    {
    [HttpPost]
            public string exporttocsv(string data)
            {  
               List<ShowNihSearchData> model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ShowNihSearchData>>(data);
            }
}
```

it is working fine after I  change `List<ShowNihSearchData>` to the string

Answer (score 0):

There is a model binding mismatch. The "exporttocsv" action expects a list of objects. You are sending it an object with the key "model", which has a string value which is a list of objects (or something, I don't know what ViewBag.alldata contains). You are also first JSON-stringifying the model into JSON, and then JSON.stringifying that *a second time*, which may or may not be what you want.

The structure of the information must match on both sides.

Answer (score 0):

If your `ShowNihSearchData` is right, ajax with below code will work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function check() {
        debugger
        var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(@ViewBag.alldata));
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/exporttocsv",
            data: { "data": model },
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {

                location.href = '@Url.Action("DownloadCSV", "Home")?success=' + data;

            }
        });
    };

</script>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer I got it what was I doing wrong?